# Non-Empty Finite Subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is not Open

Tags: general-topology

Consider $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T})$ standard topology

Definition :

> $ U \in \mathcal{T}$ if $\forall x \in U, \exists \delta$ such that $(x-\delta,x+\delta) \subset U$

If using this definition, can I say that Since $U$ is finite and nonempty, let $U :=$ {$u_1,...,u_n$}. Then I assume this set has maximum or minimum. Let $x$ be either max or min, so the definition of open sets tells that given any $\delta$, there are infinitely many points in $(x-\delta, x+\delta)$ but not in $U$, hence not subset of $U$, then we conclude $U \notin \mathcal{T}$, hence not open

Is this argument correct?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. It would be enough to state that specifically $x-\frac12\delta\notin U$ with $x=\min U$.

Comment: yes it is correct but there may be other arguments.

Comment: @user795571, any hints on the other arguments?

Comment: @Hobbit6094 Why do you need to show it has a maximum or minimum?  Your argument works anyway.  Let $x$ be *any* element of $U$ then that interval is infinite for all $\epsilon$ and therefore cannot be in $U$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant, oh, of course, just think way too far, thx

Comment: @Hobbit6094 well better too much than too little ;-)

Comment: Using the max (or min)  seems geometrically cleaner, for then it is obvious that any open interval containing the point has points outside $U$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I would disagree, he uses that an infinite set cannot be a subset of a finite set, that has nothing to do with the maximum so to introduce it is to provide a clumsy proof.

Comment: by definition, any nonempty open set has to be infinite because it contains a nondegenerate interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes ! you are absolutely right, whatever $\delta$ you will choose interval $(x-\delta, x+\delta)$ will contain infinitely many reals but $U$ is finite.